# Can "bare" TO phonons in polar materials exist by themselves, or are they always phonon-polaritons?

Tags: dispersion, phonons, quasiparticles

We know that transverse optical (TO) phonons in polar crystals couple to light strongly and can form hybrid light-matter quasi-particles called phonon-polaritons (solid lines in the figure below).

My question is, in this case, are the "bare" TO phonons (e.g. the dashed line marked green) real physical modes that can exist on their own? I can imagine that as soon a "bare" phonon mode is excited, it will generate EM fields that then affect itself, and thus quickly becomes a "coupled" polariton mode.

[image]